# Jekyll for podcast/xml - processing changes tag cases and content

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to use Jekyll to create a valid podcast feed using certain blog posts of mine. However I'm having trouble with Jekyll changing the casing and formatting of some xml tags

This is the template I have for each individual `item` of the feed:

```
    {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.layout == "podcast" %}
    <item>
        <title>{{post.title}}</title>
        <description>
            {{post.title}}

            {{ post.overview | xml_escape}}
        </description>
        <content:encoded>
            {{post.title}}<br />
            {{ post.overview | xml_escape}}<br />
            {{ post.content }}
        </content:encoded>
        <guid>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</guid>
        <link>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</link>
        <pubDate>{{ post.date | date: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" }}</pubDate>
        <itunes:image href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.thumb }}" />
        <enclosure url="{{ post.mp3link }}" length="{{ post.length }}" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </item>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The relevant parts are these two tags:

```
<link>{{ post.url }}</link>
<pubDate>{{ post.date | date: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" }}</pubDate>
```

In the output however they come out like so:

```
<link />http://www.example.com/
<pubdate>Fri, 30 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT</pubdate>
```

Link seems to be formatted as if it were a `link` tag in the `head` section of html and `pubDate` is no longer camel cased and thus invalid according to the rss standard: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt

Is there some sort of flag I need to pass or some functionality I'm missing?

Other tags are being processed just fine (image, enclosure, guid etc).

I'm using:

- jekyll 2.5.3
- ruby 1.9.3p484
- Linux Mint 17

Answer (score 0):

You must have broken XML somewhere else. Please post the complete file or else it would be hard to be very specific.

Here's what I have in mine:

Podcast:

```
<pubDate>{{ site.time | date: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT" }}</pubDate>
<link>{{ site.url }}</link>
```

Podcast Episode:

```
<link>{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}</link>
<pubDate>{{ post.date | date: "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S EST" }}</pubDate>
```

Comment: I've updated question with more details. But it is just these two tags that Jekyll is changing in the output file. Rest of the file/feed is valid.

In general Jekyll tries to "fix" the casing of the tags, but `pubDate` is the only camelCased tag there which explains why it gets changed into `pubdate`. Wondering if there is a flag or config issue I could pass to prevent this, have not found it in the documentation

As for the `link` tag, I'm not sure why that is happening.